# Req e Res no nodejs, problema na compreensão dos argumentos

Tags: javascript, node.js

Eu me vi com o problema em entender a fundo o que significa o res e req no node js, porém é preciso entender o problema, eu entendo tudo sobre o que é o res, e o que é o req e sei para que utiliza-los, porém uma função por exemplo, function soma(x, y) ela recebe os argumentos x e y para que dentro do seu corpo ela faça o processo de soma e então possamos usar o resultado, OK!

Porém no caso do req e res, o req é como no nome já diz, uma requisição, e o res é a resposta a isto, logo na minha cabeça não faz nenhum sentido a função receber a requisição e a resposta.

A questão que fica é, como é processado isto na máquina?

Pois para mim o conceito que fica é, eu chego numa padaria e quero pão de sal, mas antes eu tenho que perguntar se tem pão de sal, porém eu já sei que tem de pão sal, então eu pergunto ao padeiro e ao mesmo tempo dou a resposta a ele, e depois fico esperando ele me responder algo que eu já o respondi.

Pelo menos foi assim que ficou entendido, e sei que esta errado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É que nesse caso a função do express usa o protocolo HTTP, que é baseado em **req**uisição e **res**posta, então o `req` é um objeto que contém informações sobre a solicitação HTTP do evento, informações do header, experimente dar um `console.log(req)`, ja o `res` é basicamente o objeto que contem a resposta do servidor.

Comment: Acho que entendi, o res é recebido na função pois ele é um argumento da express, e então manipulamos do jeito que quisermos para dar a resposta que queremos.
Ok, obrigado.